# Azure DevOps ( On-premises ) | Configuration Build Process & Docker Image creation for Nexus Repository

Tags: azure-devops, nexus, azure-devops-extensions

iam new with the topic Azure DevOps & Nexus Repository.
My code is committed on Azure DevOps On-premises. And the way Azure DevOps and Azure registry works fine.

But now i struggle with **configuration Nexus**, does i need this tutorial ? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/nexus-build-extension-for-team-services/

When yes where i get information for this properties:

- Repository Id
- Group Id
- Artifact Id
- Artifact Version,..

because those properties are needed for configuration that.
After i speaking with my Nexus colleuges he mean its look like Maven configuration.

So maybe the way is wrong ?

**Conclusion what i want to achive:**

After i have committed my code in Azure DevOps On-premises, i want to configure a build process that create a docker image which move this into nexus repository.

Kind regards,

Unknown

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Does the answer could solve your issue and puzzle?  If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Answer (score 2):

No, not wrong.

We have open the source of this extension in Github, see this [`vsts-nexus`](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-nexus) repos.

Before the code analysis, we need to know the logic of it. In this extension, we achieve the feature uploading the file to Nexus Repository Manager with **Nexus 2.x Rest API**, which URI is:

```
https://local:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/content?r={xx}&g={xx}&a={xx}&v={xx}&p={xx}&c={xx}" > xxx.jar
```

In this URI, `r` is `repositoryId`, `g` is `groupId`, `a` is `artifactId`, `v` is `artifactVersion`, `c` is `classifier`, `p` is `packaging`. That's why your colleague think its look like Maven configuration, because we are using this API as the logic of extension.

See this script file: [NexusTask.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-nexus/blob/master/Extension/artifactUpload/NexusTask.ts).

```
var nexusUploadUrl = Util.addUrlSegment(serverEndpointUrl, 'service/local/artifact/maven/content');
tl.debug('nexusUploadUrl=' + nexusUploadUrl);
     ...
     ...
     ...
var formData = {
    // Pass a simple key-value pair
    r: repositoryId,
    g: groupId,
    a: artifactId,
    v: artifactVersion,
    c: classifier,
    p: packaging,
    e: extension,
    // Pass data via Streams
    my_file: fs.createReadStream(fileName)
};

var postData: any = { url: nexusUploadUrl, formData: formData, strictSSL: !trustSSL };
```

This is the short section of script. You can get clearly know the API and its parameters what the extension used.

So, there's no wrong on this extension and task, just its logic is using the Nexus 2.x API.

But, you need to pay attention about this extension only support **Nexus 2.x** until now. If what you are using is Nexus 3.x, you'd better use a Maven pom.xml file to upload an artifact into Nexus via Nexus' Maven support.

As what you want is build a docker image then upload it to Nexus, you can use Docker task to build the docker image, then use this task or Maven to upload this image to Nexus.

Comment: Liang -MSFT: 
thanks for sharing your knowledge about this. :) :) :)
I will check & try.

Comment: Welcome:-) You can also try with the Nexus 3.x API to push the image: `curl -v -F r={repostory} -F e={extension} -F g={group id} -F a={artifact id} -F v={version} -F p={packaging} -F file={file path} -u {username}:{password} http://localhost:8081/repository/{repostory}/`

Comment: @Unknown Hi, how about the result? Could you achieve all you want successfully? Did you still has any puzzle in this ticket? Just feel free to ask here.